# Which Linux distribution is best for hosting Minecraft server?

Tags: game, linux-distribution

I have a computer than I will use for, and likely dedicate to hosting a Minecraft server, and I was told that Linux is better for that. I had some experience with Linux in the past, but I stopped using it around 3 years ago.

My PC is Core i3, 16 GB RAM, I will buy SSD soon, probably Core i7.

I want to be able to download the distribution, install and then use out of the box, without too much tweaking (no more than an hour of a relatively inexperienced user).
I would prefer this distribution to have graphical interface, but command prompt is OK.

Comment: Did you Google at all? `linux minecraft distro` First 4 hits: **[Mine OS - easy minecraft hosting solution](https://minecraft.codeemo.com/)**
[MineOS](https://minecraft.codeemo.com/) Turnkey is the current flagship distribution of MineOS. Based on the proven Debian foundation. **[7 Steps To Install And Optimize Minecraft For Linux.](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/7-steps-install-optimize-minecraft-linux/)** **[What distro do you find best to work with minecraft?](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1893227)** **[Best linux OS to run Minecraft - Discussion - Minecraft Discussion](http://www

Comment: Mawg, could you please post an answer about MineOS Turnkey? I think it is the best answer possible, I am many would definitely upvote it :-) Also, friendly reminder that writing "google it" should be avoided, Stack Exchange intends to become THE reference and better than a Google search, details at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80730/i-mean-still-google-it-answers. In this case I think it is a great question even if  answers are not difficult to find :-)

Answer (score 3):

[Ubuntu Server](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server). Free, Doesn't use many resources and very very well documented.It is also more stable, lighter on resources and it is compatible with nearly all hardware out of the box.

However,these are some of the system requirements;

- 700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
- 512 MiB RAM (system memory)
- 5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive
  but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
- VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution.
- Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media.

---

Or else you can try to figureout more on these as well for your future benefits:Ubuntu Server(mentioned already above), [Debian](https://www.debian.org/) and CentOS;are all great choices. Ubuntu has a lot more "stuff" in it, so if you are looking for something semi-lightweight for a VPS I would recommend Debian. It's package management is top notch and it will run fine.

[CentOS](https://www.centos.org/) is also a good operating system for explicit serving, if you are looking at running LAMP stack on your server, it is also my recommendation. Most other distributions will sink in quality a bit or be too difficult for a simple server even though they may offer maximum customization (Arch, Gentoo).

Comment: Is it fine-tuned out-of-the-box for Minecraft?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I don't think any general use OS is going to be "fine tuned" for a single application, though that might exist in industrial applications / specialty software. However, there are operating systems that require less overhead to run, leaving more resources available for the applications running on them. A lightweight Linux installation would probably use less RAM and be less demanding on the CPU, potentially allowing Minecraft to utilize more of the system's power.

Comment: @Shrout1 Some OSes like FreePBX or TurnkeySamba are tuned for a specific application (not sure there is one for Minecraft though). Here are the kind of OS parameters that a specialized Linux distro would have already researched and optimized: https://gist.github.com/kgriffs/4027835#file-sysctl-conf-L40

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Very true! Specialized OSes do exist, though neither CentOS or Ubuntu is going to be tuned out of the box for something like Minecraft. Probably wouldn't be too hard to configure it that way :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Docker to run it in the same way on any Linux: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server#Docker